# UltraNumericEditor doesn't show zero value

Tags: infragistics

this is my first experience with Infragistics components.
I have WinForm project with form including UltraNumericEditor with this setting:

```
FormatString: ### ### ###.##
MinValue: 0
Nullable: true
NullText: [N/A]
NumericType: Double
TabNavigation: NextControl
```

On component is no event. 
If I want to write into "text box" 0 (zero), text box is empty, I don't see any char, but in code behind this component return right value.

Other numbers are allright and I don't know why.
Does anyone experience with this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because you use '#' as `Formatstring`

you have to use something like

```
### ### ##0.00
```

or

```
n2
```

or

```
C2' for currency
```

this is from msdn

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

here is a link for better understanding

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)